# is there another way to get to my desktop directory in gitbash

Tags: directory

I am trying to change directories into my desktop but i keep getting this message.
is there another way to access my desktop from here.

mj_pr@markiem MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ cd desktop
bash: cd: desktop: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to just right click on the folder that you want to access from your desktop and open your terminal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).